# NERDTree failing on VIM

Tags: vim, iterm2, nerdtree

NerdTree isn't working with Vim from iTerm2 for me.
It will show the current directory listing but won't let me traverse deeper into the file system, but I can traverse upwards.
All directory listings are preceded by `?~V?` and I have no idea why. I believe this is the reason that I can't go deeper into directory listings.
Does anyone know why this may be?

Comment: It looks like an encoding issue. See [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/387777/what-could-cause-strange-characters-in-vim). Also, if you don't use NERDTree's bookmarking feature, you might consider using the buit-in Netrw plugin instead.

Comment: Indeed, it was an encoding issue. Don't know why I didn't think of it. I needed to rebuild `Vim` with multi-byte support, this link solved the issue [source](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3766204/vim-doesnt-support-unicode).  essentially: `./configure --with-features=big      make   make install`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an encoding issue. I had to rebuild `Vim` with bulti-byte support.

Essentially:

```
./configure --with-features=big 
make 
make install
```